# Git lock in some files

Tags: git, jenkins

I am working on Linux (bash), where I launch 3 simultaneous jobs (identical at the beginning as they need to check out some code from git) from Jenkins, and sometimes I am getting this error:

```
fatal: Unable to create '/path/my_project/.git/index.lock': File exists
```

Each job runs a few git commands like: `git reset --hard origin/master;`

After analyzing this, I come to the conclusion that, sometimes when a job is running a git command, the other job is tries to use a file which is locked. So I need to implement some strategy for this situation not to occur - to prevent this lock errors.

Any ideas how I could resolve this?

Comment: I'm trying to prevent parallel execution of git commands for the same repository. Otherwise, I often get this error. The logic associated with the index.lock file is needed to ensure the integrity of the repository.

Comment: I can I can check if file exists, and if its exists than sleep a few seconds...

Comment: I think what you suggest is also a good option.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to run competing operations in the same repository and/or working tree.

You can attack this problem two ways:

- do your own job-queueing, so that jobs run sequentially, or
- use multiple Git working trees and/or clones, so that the jobs are not competing with each other in the first place.

Whether `git worktree add` will suffice depends on whether your operations are purely working-tree operations.

Note that Jenkins is *already* a job-queueing system (see [Multiple build queues in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8731422/1256452)).  There are many other options as well.  *Git* is not a job-queueing system; use some external one.